# I am using jquery sortable() for my table tr drag drop into the same table, how to move the tr through button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to drag and drop the tr using the button and not the entire tr

```js
// Drag and drop is enabled: Make the rows within the same table sortable
$("#myTable tbody").sortable({
  helper: 'clone',
  start: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.addClass("dragging");
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.removeClass("dragging");
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td><button class="draggable">Drag</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td><button class="draggable">Drag</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 3</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td><button class="draggable">Drag</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Please [edit] and replace the PHP with relevant HTML to make a [mcve] - I made an attempt but it is better it is your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`handle`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle)

```js
// Drag and drop is enabled: Make the rows within the same table sortable
$("table tbody").sortable({
  handle: ".handle",
  helper: 'clone',
  start: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.addClass("dragging");
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.removeClass("dragging");
  },
})//.disableSelection();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td class="handle">≡</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td class="handle">≡</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 3</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td class="handle">≡</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```